# How to request HTML of whole page via SharePoint GraphAPI? (not only WebParts)

Tags: web-part, css, html, graph-api

I'm trying to display SharePoint pages on a webpage through SharePoint GraphAPI.

I used WebPart endpoint to get HTML content of SharePoint page (`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webpart?view=graph-rest-beta`). But it doesn't return some of the parent divs which are needed to content be styled properly (to have same styles as in Sharepoint preview).

For example this comes from GraphAPI as a Webpart:

```
"innerHtml": "<blockquote><p><i><strong>Something</strong></i></p></blockquote>"
```

But when I inspect the preview in SharePoint the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="ControlZone ControlZone--clean a_b_50a7110f" data-automation-id="CanvasControl" id="a12ed8f6-9d90-4deb-9faf-2c0e5ea6e8a0">
    <div class="ControlZone--control">
       <div data-sp-feature-tag="Rich Text Editor" class="rte-webpart rte--ck5 rte--read-ck5 uniformSpacingForElements" data-sp-feature-instance-id="a12ed8f6-9d90-4deb-9faf-2c0e5ea6e8a0" dir="auto">
          <div data-automation-id="textBox" class="ck-content rteEmphasis root-154">
             <blockquote><p><i><strong>Something</strong></i></p></blockquote>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Exist there a way how to get complete HTML of the block via API? Styles aplied in SharePoint looks like:

```
.rte--ck5 .ck-content blockquote:last-child {}
.root-154 blockquote {}
```

So because of the missing parent tags the styles are not applied in the case of HTML content taken from API.

Thank you

Comment: Couldn't you just get the entire page html via drive -> item -> content?

Comment: I need to get the HTML content via GraphAPI.

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean. I get the entire HTML content of a page using path mentioned above. I don't download the file. But get the content.

Comment: Have you tried using the SharePoint REST API endpoint? `GET https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items(1)?$select=Title,CanvasContent1`

Comment: This method might return more complete HTML content, including the parent divs. 
`GET https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,CanvasContent1&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'Employee.aspx'`